# Why do I have a lot of error messages in my Controller since I upgraded Intellij IDEA ultimate from 2020.3 to 2021.1?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Just updated Intellij IDEA ultimate 2021.1 I work with Springboot, maven and Thymeleaf for my Java programs.
Since then my earlier projects show a massive red errors in the controller on every imported function. But the project stil works!
How can I resolve those red "so called" errors and what could be the reason of this change?

Comment: It was not about debugging. Like Emerson Micu said, it was about "invalidate caches" after an update. I only could show it with an image which is not allowed... Because the program worked. So what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be related to IntelliJ Cache.
Open IntelliJ and **go to** "File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart..."

[image]

Comment: For older projects it is solved, thankyou. 
For new projecs I still cannot import anything. 
If I put "alt+enter" on the @controller to import then I get only: "Make "MainController" package private"   and "Create Test". Nothing else.

Comment: It was solved. The other error was my fault, should have been with Capital @Controller. Thankyou very much